# How to use AutoFixture in this case?

Tags: c#, autofixture

I have the following code:

```
var boundArgument = new BoundArgumentOption
{
    PatientId = patientId
};

var mockRepositoryFactory = A.Fake<IRepositoryFactory>();

var sut = new HtmlOutputBuilder(mockRepositoryFactory);

var patientRecord = // Some record;

var mockRepository = A.Fake<IRepository>();
A.CallTo(() => mockRepository.Get(boundArgument)).Returns(patientRecord);
A.CallTo(() => mockRepositoryFactory.Create(boundArgument)).Returns(mockRepository);

string actualResult = sut.BuildReport(boundArgument);

actualResult.Should().Be(expectedHtmlContent);
```

and that passes the test.

Then I tried using AutoFixture as follows:

```
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoFakeItEasyCustomization());

var boundArgument = fixture.Create<BoundArgumentOption>();

var mockRepositoryFactory = A.Fake<IRepositoryFactory>();

fixture.Freeze(mockRepositoryFactory);

var sut = fixture.Create<HtmlOutputBuilder>();

var patientRecord = //Some record;

boundArgument.PatientId = patientId;

var mockRepository = A.Fake<IRepository>();
A.CallTo(() => mockRepository.Get(boundArgument)).Returns(patientRecord);

A.CallTo(() => mockRepositoryFactory.Create(boundArgument)).Returns(mockRepository);

string actualResult = sut.BuildReport(boundArgument);

actualResult.Should().Be(expectedHtmlContent);
```

which fails. In particular, the `patientRecord` in the second instance is not getting populated properly.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the value of the `expectedHtmlContent`?

Comment: @NikosBaxevanis It shouldn't really matter what the value of `expectedHmtlContent` is but FYI it's actually an Html string which I'll write to a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note**: I couldn't compile the test you provided.. however *it seems* that all you have to do is:

```
fixture.Inject(mockRepositoryFactory);
```

You may try the following:

```
[Fact]
public void TestWithAutoFixtureImperatively()
{
    // Fixture setup
    var fixture = new Fixture()
        .Customize(new AutoFakeItEasyCustomization());

    var expectedRecord = fixture.Create<string>();
    var boundArgOption = fixture.Create<BoundArgumentOption>();

    var repositoryStub = A.Fake<IRepository>();
    A.CallTo(() => 
        repositoryStub
            .Get(boundArgOption))
            .Returns(expectedRecord);

    var repositoryFactoryStub = A.Fake<IRepositoryFactory>();
    A.CallTo(() => 
        repositoryFactoryStub
            .Create(boundArgOption))
            .Returns(repositoryStub);

    fixture.Inject(repositoryFactoryStub);

    var sut = fixture.Create<HtmlOutputBuilder>();

    // Exercise system
    string result = sut.BuildReport(boundArgOption);

    // Verify outcome
    result.Should().Be(expectedRecord);

    // Teardown
}
```

We *inject* the `IRepositoryFactory` so that the same, injected, instance will be passed in the SUT.

---

Alternatively, you can also use AutoFixture [declaratively](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/10/08/AutoDataTheoriesWithAutoFixture.aspx) with the xUnit.net [extension](http://nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.Xunit/):

```
[Theory, AutoDomainData]
public void TestWithAutoFixtureDeclaratively(
    string expectedRecord,
    BoundArgumentOption boundArgOption,
    Fake<IRepository> repositoryStub,
    [Frozen]Fake<IRepositoryFactory> repositoryFactoryStub,
    HtmlOutputBuilder sut)
{
    // Fixture setup
    A.CallTo(() =>
        repositoryStub
            .FakedObject
            .Get(boundArgOption))
            .Returns(expectedRecord);

    A.CallTo(() =>
        repositoryFactoryStub
            .FakedObject
            .Create(boundArgOption))
            .Returns(repositoryStub.FakedObject);

    // Exercise system
    string result = sut.BuildReport(boundArgOption);

    // Verify outcome
    result.Should().Be(expectedRecord);

    // Teardown
}
```

The `AutoDomainDataAttribute` is defined as:

```
internal class AutoDomainDataAttribute : CompositeDataAttribute
{
    internal AutoDomainDataAttribute()
        : base(
            new AutoDataAttribute(
                new Fixture().Customize(
                    new AutoFakeItEasyCustomization())))
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: The code supplied was not meant to be compilable :). I wanted to get rid of fluff. Having said that the code supplied worked :). Thank you very much. I haven't seen the Inject method detailed much anywhere. Is there somewhere where I can find more information about that? Also what is the difference between Inject and Freeze? Should that be a separate question?

Comment: You are welcome! `Inject` customizes the `Fixture` instance to always return the same, injected, value. `Freeze` will create the value for you and then it calls `Inject` internally.

Comment: Details about how `Inject` works can be found at https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture/FixtureRegistrar.cs#L10-75